# Can an .ipsw firmware restore image's origin be verified?

Tags: ios, ipsw

Given an `.ipsw` iOS firmware restore image, can its origin be verified (e.g. through checking a digital signature) to provide assurance that it is actually from Apple and it hasn't been tampered with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All IPSW SHA1 hashes can be found on [The iPhone Wiki - Firmware](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Firmware).

You can get the SHA1 of your downloaded IPSW by running the following Terminal command:

```
openssl sha1 <path-to-ipsw>
```

The output can be compared to the relevant SHA1 provided on the wiki.

Comment: This is very useful information,  though I was hoping for some sort of digital signature.  However, based on further reading, it doesn't appear such an animal exists.  Thanks!