# Can I get the ipsw file off my iPhone 3gs and install it on my iPhone 4s?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipsw

I still have my old iPhone 3gs (AT&T) with iOS 6. I have a back up of it as well. I also have a iPhone 4s (Sprint) with iOS 7.

Can I grab the ipsw file off my iPhone 3gs and install it on my iPhone 4s?

I will not install any ipsw from the net. It is not worth the risk of getting an infected or spyware file.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! If one of the answers posted here answers your question, please accept it by clicking the checkbox next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, even if you obtained the IPSW, it would not install since there are different IPSWs for different devices.

You can check the authenticity of an IPSW per this question:

- [Can an .ipsw firmware restore image's origin be verified?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101757/can-an-ipsw-firmware-restore-images-origin-be-verified)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reputable website that gives a lot of information about each IPSW, and it gives you the direct link to the file on Apple's servers for each one. Famous jailbreakers [@icj_](https://twitter.com/icj_) and [@iH8sn0w](https://twitter.com/icj_) run the website.

http://www.icj.me/ios/all

Comment: Thank You. I am reluctant to use any file not from apple itself.